# how to save model and apply it on a test dataset on java

Tags: java, weka

I have the following code in which I applied a classifier on training data set , I want to save it (with the cross-validation ) as a model . and apply it again on a test data set.

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader ;

public class EECS_738
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // training
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Sumiah/Desktop/ProjectTraining&TestingData/project/EECS738_Train_Project.arff"));
      Instances train =new Instances (reader);
      train.setClassIndex(0);     
      reader.close();

      J48 j48 = new J48();
      j48.buildClassifier(train);
      Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
      eval.crossValidateModel(j48, train, 10 , new Random(1));

      System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\n Results \n=====\n",true));
      System.out.println(eval.fMeasure(1)+" "+eval.precision(1)+" "+eval.recall(1)+" ");           
   }   
}
```

Comment: Wekas classifier implement serializable so use an ObjectOutputStream

Comment: I did not get *with the cross validation* part. The model you are going to save will be from the entire training data. Cross validation is just an evaluation process.

Comment: @RushdiShams In fact, the function buildClassifier is actually embedded in the eval.crossValidateModel so calling the j48.buildClassifier won't work. You can safely remove it out of your code without hurting the model performance, remove obscure, and improve the code runtime.

Answer (score 7):

For versions greater than 3.5.5 it's as simple as:

```
J48 j48 = new J48();
j48.buildClassifier(train);
weka.core.SerializationHelper.write("/some/where/j48.model", j48);
```

And loading is just:

```
Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("/some/where/j48.model");
```

See [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization) for more info and how to do it in legacy versions!